# Prove that for any two numbers $0 \leq a < b \leq m - 1$ it is not possible that $m|b - a$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

As the title suggest im having difficulty approaching how or where to start proving this. Only thing i can derive from the given is that $m|b - a$ is equivalent to $b - a = mk$ for some k

Comment: This $k$ is an integer. Show that $0 < b-a < m$ and you will have a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

$$0\leq a< b\leq m-1\implies$$

$$0\le a <b< m\implies$$

$$m>b \implies$$

$$m>b-a\implies$$

$m $ cannot divide $ b-a$.

Comment: ohh i totally missed the fact that if b < m - 1 then b < m. Thank you for input

Comment: @UnKnoWnZ No, if $b\le m-1$ then $b<m$.

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah: no. if $b < m - 1$ then $b \le m- 1$, so $b < m$. You can't say that UnKnoWnZ's comment is wrong.

Comment: @RobArthan Your comment has not been upvoted. It means something.

Comment: "hh i totally missed the fact that if b < m - 1 then b < m. Thank you for input"  Yes, but we *don't* know that $b < m-1$.  We only know that $b \le m-1$.  But that's okay.  If $b\le m-1$ then $b < m$.  (That was the purpose of hamam_Abdallah's "No"-- not that you were wrong [you were correct-- but that we don't know $b < m-1$.)